# Finding which validation failed

Tags: c#, winforms, validation

i have a button in my form that is saving data to my database . Before saving, the button is trying to validate the from . I need to know which of my controls fails in its validation event

```
private void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
     if (MyParentform.ValidateChildren())
       {
         BindingSource1.EndEdit();
         MyManager.UpdateAll(MyDataset);
       }
     else
       {
       Messagebox.Show("Control " + MyFailedControl + "failed !")
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to change the logic of your event handler. Instead of returning `bool`, return `null` *or* the `Control` which is invalid so that you will be able to report about:

```
private void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
     if (MyParentform.GetInvalidControl() == null)
       {
         BindingSource1.EndEdit();
         MyManager.UpdateAll(MyDataset);
       }
     else
       {
         Messagebox.Show(string.Format("Control {0} failed", MyParentform.GetInvalidControl().Name))
       }
   }
```

Comment: how to get the InvalidControls ?

Comment: @Theodore just implement the required logic.